# How to combine an uploaded X3D file with an inline node?

Tags: inline, fileapi, x3d, x3dom

In my [code example](https://jsfiddle.net/c7tkvaw3/3/) I have an upload button and an x3d scene.
After choosing an x3d file from the local file system the method `URL.createObjectURL` is called.

The content of my html file looks like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
        <title>Include an external X3D-File</title>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='https://x3dom.org/download/dev/x3dom.js'> </script>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='https://x3dom.org/download/dev/x3dom.css'/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="file" onchange="onFileChange(event)" accept=".x3d">
        <x3d width='500px' height='400px'>
            <scene id="scene">
            </scene>
        </x3d>
    </body>

    <script>
        function onFileChange(event) {
          var inline = document.createElement("Inline");
          inline.setAttribute("nameSpaceName", "Inline");
          inline.setAttribute("mapDEFToID", true);
          var url = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
          inline.setAttribute("url", url);
          document.getElementById("scene").appendChild(inline);
          console.log("ObjectURL: " + url);
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

An .x3d file could look like this:

```
<x3d width="500px" height="400px">
  <scene>
    <shape>
      <appearance>
        <material diffuseColor='red'></material>
      </appearance>
      <box></box>
    </shape>
  </scene>
</x3d>
```

I want to use the created object url for a new generated inline node but unfortunately the model is not showing up. Instead a loading circle stays at the upper left corner like in this 
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ondUK.png) or in image below.

[image]

Did I overlook something or is there another way to load an x3d file into the browser and access it from the inline node?

**Update:**

In the meantime I've solved the problem by myself.
Which I did not think about was to use `contentType='model/x3d+xml'` with Inline because the blob url does not end with .x3d.

Comment: Hello Sebastian, Welcome to Stackoverflow. Your question is correctly written except for Code Example and Screenshot. For the screenshot it is always better to make a paste copy of image directly in question. For Code Example, you can also use code snipped documentated at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks. Stackoverflow recommands that source code are saved on Stackoverflow and not on another site so that question is fully written on it. Can you do this little change ?

Comment: @schlebe Thanks for the advice. When I try to paste the image directly I get a warning from stackoverflow that my reputation has to be at least 10. Currently I have no other choice but to create a link.

Comment: hello Sebastian, I have added image myself and I have also try to define your code in a snipped but this has not working perhaps because you sample need a .x3d file. For your issue, can you give an example without the need to use a file so that I can define a snipped. If this is impossible, I will stop to insist.

Comment: Hello schlebe, I've added the content of an exemplary .x3d file. Everything between the <scene> nodes could also be inserted directly under the scene node of the html file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime I've solved the problem by myself. Which I did not think about was to use `contentType='model/x3d+xml'` with Inline because the blob url does not end with .x3d.

The final solution is now:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
        <title>Include an external X3D-File</title>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='https://x3dom.org/download/dev/x3dom.js'> </script>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='https://x3dom.org/download/dev/x3dom.css'/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="file" onchange="onFileChange(event)" accept=".x3d">
        <x3d width='500px' height='400px'>
            <scene id="scene">
            </scene>
        </x3d>
    </body>

    <script>
        function onFileChange(event) {
          var inline = document.createElement("Inline");
          inline.setAttribute("nameSpaceName", "Inline");
          inline.setAttribute("mapDEFToID", true);
          inline.setAttribute("contentType", "model/x3d+xml");
          var url = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
          inline.setAttribute("url", url);
          document.getElementById("scene").appendChild(inline);
          console.log("ObjectURL: " + url);
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Good for you. But can you write your solution in your last answer giving some lines of code. I propose that you give your last <script> content because I suppose that 'contentType' has been added in <script>. I suppose but I'm not sure. That is the reason for which I propose that you add your solution in your last answer.